# The type or namespace name 'BasePage' could not be found

Tags: .net, reference

In **VS 2012** I have the file BasePage in the App_Code directory. No errors in that file.

When trying to compile my project I get:

> The type or namespace name 'BasePage' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

On this line of code:

```
public partial class Contact : BasePage
```

No namespace is used and both files are in the same asp.net web forms project. The file that generates the error in root and BasePage in **App_Code**.

Not sure how to solve this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created the empty web application and copied files from a site that doesn't have a project.

First added referenced to the dll files in the bin directory (solution explorer => right click references and browse).

Then click on the "Show all fies" button in the solution explorer. Right clicked App_Code => include in project.

Compiled the project (need to do this before adding other stuff).

Start adding other folders to project like the UserControls folder and compile each time I added them.

At the end added all the aspx and cs files in root and compiled again without an error.

Comment: On the right track for me - adding my base class page to app_code solved my "cannot find class" error.  Thanks.